# Refresh state tree in redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage

I am new to react-redux and finding difficulty in data flow.i have multiple reducers in my redux structure which are combined through "*combineReducers*".

Now store is populated with value in localStorage.It is initialized well all the actions are also performed through "*dispatch()*".but here's a scenario where there is need to refresh the whole store tree from locastorage as at a point localstorage is updated but store isn't updated until refreshing the page.

Tried solution is following:

1. An action is declared which is dispatched when localstorage is updated.and it is also listened in main store file as follows.

   ```
    let currentValue
   function handleChange() {
     let previousValue = currentValue
     currentValue = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('data')) 
     if (previousValue !== currentValue) {
       console.log(
         'Some deep nested property changed from',
         previousValue,
         'to',
         currentValue
       )
     }
   }

   store.subscribe(handleChange);
   ```

console says store is updated here but state isnt updated here neither the components showing that updation.

Any kind suggestion please what m doing wrong.

Comment: Any chance you can share the reducers and the dispatcher that should be responsible for updating the full state tree?

Comment: Also, it would be interesting to see the setup of your provider (that contains the appstore). I could imagine you might need to trigger a full load action, or simply rerender the provider with the new store

Comment: sorry what do u mean by setup of provider?do u want to see code directory setup?

Comment: i write this reducer just because the reason that calling one action in reducer will call all reducers in tree.that reducer is actually doing nothing instead of invoking reducers so that they can update themselves according to store.